# Preguntar por archivo sincronizado en Dropbox

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

tengo una duda que mas que código necesito de su orientación.
Me encontraba realizando una prueba en C# en la que copiaba archivos de la ruta local de mi Dropbox, en dicha prueba note que en algunos casos copiaba archivos que aun no estaban totalmente sincronizados(Aparentemente) ya que me los reconocía como corruptos (los copiado y el de dropbox) y luego a los minutos me mostraba el archivo como legible (solo el de dropbox) 
 
Para no alargar mucho este escrito, mi pregunta es : 
 **¿Es posible saber que archivo esta sincronizado totalmente en mi cuenta de Dropbox (la pagina web) desde C#?** 
No sé si me hago entender, pero lo que busco es preguntar directamente a la pagina por el archivo, no a la carpeta local de mi equipo donde sincroniza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropbox expone una api que podrias consultar para revisar los archivos que se subieron a la cuenta

Usando `c#` cuentas con librerias que referenciar desde `nuget`

[Dropbox.Api](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dropbox.Api/)

Despues tienes una documentacion completa sobre la api

[Dropbox api documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation)

al igual que un sdk con ejemplos de codigo

[dropbox-sdk-dotnet](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/tree/master/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/Dropbox.Api.Tests)

Si tienes las credenciales podras obtener un `token` de seguridad para invocar la api

Comment: Gracias Leandro, me informare al respecto! :D